# convert sqlite query to postgres

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I have the following query from sqlite and would like to convert it to postgres:

```
select date(date, '-'||strftime('%w', date)||' days') as date from msgs group by date order by date asc limit 10;
```

update:

I believe this could do it: `select (date::date - extract(dow from date)::int)::date as d from msgs group by d order by d asc limit 10;`

Comment: What part needs converted? Have you tried using it with Postgre, or checking if there are any incompatible parts used?

Comment: the whole statement needs to be converted.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with SQLite functions: The expression `date(date, '-'||strftime('%w', date)||' days')` evaluates to the last Sunday on or before the date `date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends.  Is it more important to group by date and then mangle the output to the format you want? Or are you better off grouping by date(date, '-'||strftime('%w', date)||' days')?  If you wanna group by just date, then do something like

select date(x.date, '-'||strftime('%w', x.date)||' days') from (select date from msgs group by date order by date asc limit 10) as x;

Otherwise group by date(date, '-'||strftime('%w', date)||' days') and you're done.